# How to shift indentation tho right and left in Emacs Evil (Spacemacs) when nothing is selected?

Tags: emacs, indentation, evil

When I am in visual mode, `parinfer-shift-right` and `parinfer-shift-left` work fine. But in normal mode these commands have no effect.

How to make these commands work in normal mode, when nothing is selected?